# Dynamically change page title from URL param

Tags: urls, title, seo, parameter

I currently use SEO plugin but I need some extra help because the plugin cannot help me in this case.

I have a page that displays data based on a URL parameter (ie. http://example.com/?user=john25). I would like to incorporate this parameter to the page title. That is, I want the page title to become something like "Entries from john25".

I would appreciate some help on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in your header.php file (or where ever you are setting your page titles in your templates)

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['user'])) : ?>
<title>Entries from <?php echo(htmlspecialchars($_GET['user'], ENT_QUOTES)) ?></title>
<?php else: ?>
<title>Normal page title here</title>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Without more info on what plugin you are using, or how your page titles are currently being set, this is the best I can recommend

Comment: Please do not delete an answer and repost the same content as a new answer. Rather file an [edit] to the existing answer if you need to add/remove or change something. Continuing this will get your account suspended by the system. (*Hint: 10K+ users can see deleted posts ;-)*).

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use values from a `GET` variable without sanitizing and validating it. It can contain malicious code, which will infect your site

Comment: Thanks Pieter for the advice, but the answer was accidentally reposted due to  miss clicking after going back in my browser, the original was edited.

Comment: As for sanitizing the GET variable that's a valid point, I'll update my answer. The ideal way would be to use whats available in the wordpress templates already, rather that using a GET param if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a nice solution but (if I am not mistaken) applies to all pages, right? In any case, I use Yoast SEO to rewrite my titles. Please let me know if you require more information. As for your existing reply, is there another place I could place it? This is because I use a child theme (Enfold) and it would be better if for example I could put it in child theme's function.php